# Link-to helper to dynamically assign class

Tags: ember.js

I understand that:

> When the rendered link matches the current route, and the same object instance is passed into the helper, then the link is given class="active".
>   http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/links/

Can a class name other than "active" be passed to the template by the link-to helper when it match the current route?

More specifically, I would like that that the `<li>` tag generated by the link-to help get the `class="open"` when the current route match the route of the link-to helper.

tks

**UPDATE**

The below answer from jasonmit work for dynamic routes where your need to pass an argument. Since my route is static, I do not pass an argument. Also, I needed the `<li>` to be assigned the class Open. Hence, I nested two link-to. The first link-to generate the `<li>` tag and add `class="open"` when the link-to match the route. The second link-to generate a `<a>` tag which is the link in HTML.

```
{{#link-to 'communications' tagName="li" activeClass="open"}}
  {{#link-to 'communications'}}
    <i class="icon-rocket"></i>
    <span class="title">communication</span>
  {{/link-to}}
{{/link-to}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{link-to 'home' 'home' activeClass='opened'}}
```

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/5fe2d63a7dab0484cad9e729886ac71b4c05f1fd/packages/ember-routing-handlebars/lib/helpers/link_to.js#L96

Comment: Thanks jasonmit. Your solution work with dynamic routes. Since, my route is static, I performed the modifications indicated in the above update.

Comment: Is there a way to declare this in one place? This make my markup awful